# How to prevent sql injection in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection

This is a old topic, but I am still having problem with it, so want to get some new idea here.

I used to check | in parameter, but it seems now ; is a separator to check too.

It suggests to use `sp_executesql` with parameters to prevent SQL injection, but I am not sure if I can do that.

What I try to do is collect filters from client side and run dynamic SQL to get result, for example, from client side, I could send a request with the below filters to SQL:

```
id=1234 name=david date=2014/01/01
```

I will create dynamic sql like

```
select * 
from members 
where id = 1234 
  and name like 'david%' 
  and crea_date = '2014/01/01'
```

The search column could be any random list of field of a table, so I cannot run `sp_executesql` like

```
sp_executesql N'select * from members where id=@id and name like @name and crea_date=@crea_date',N'@id int,@name nvachar(100),@crea_date datetime', ....
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameters, no problem. Make the SQL dynamic, but make the generated SQL refer to parameters. Unconditionally pass in a `@name` parameter if you need to, just make the `name like @name` part of your `where` clause dynamic. If you don't search on name, simply ignore the parameter in your SQL.

If you do not want to hard code the parameter names, name them `param1`, `param2` etc.

Depending on how you are executing it, you may even be able to get rid of the dummy parameters when you aren't using them.

Comment: but as I mentioned, the list of fields are dynamic, how does it work with name like param1,param2 etc,  for example, one filter could be "id=1 name=david date1=2014/01/01' , another could be "name=d age=3 gender=male salary=4000"

Comment: from that string, how do you build dynamic sql with all params and pass them

Comment: @wyx2000 You know field names and parameter names can be different, right? If you are dealing with a situation in which you cannot dynamically choose parameter names, generate SQL like `where name like @param1`. The only problem is you have a hard coded maximum number of parameters that way, but you can add more as needed.

Comment: @wyx2000 So you would generate `where id=@param1 and name like @param2 and date1=@param3`

Comment: so you are saying I should declare max like @ param1 to @ param100, and if there are 20 fields involved, assign them to @ param1 to @ param20, but after that how do I call it, do I have to write code for each number of params? for example, if @ paramtotal=20 execute sp_executesql N'...',N'...',@ param1,@ param2,@ param3....@ param20

Comment: @wyx2000 Always pass in all parameters if you don't see any way of avoiding that. If you only use one fifth of them, that won't be a problem: the remaining 80% will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Default answer: Use prepared statements.

Comment: I am handling the client filter string in SQL end, not middle tier.

Comment: Why are you putting together SQL strings on that level then? Shouldn't you just pass the filter parameters down and create the Query in a lower layer then?